# Find Adjoint of linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Given two fixed matrices $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ I have a linear map $F:\mathbb{R}^{pm\times 1}\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ that can be described as follows:
$$
F(x) = \texttt{sum(} A \odot B \texttt{ reshape(}x\texttt{, (p, m))} \texttt{, axis=1)}
$$
where $\odot$ is the [elementwise product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)). Basically, we first reshape $x$ into a matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times m}$, then we compute $A \odot (BX)$ which is a $n\times m$ matrix, and finally we sum across the columns to get a $n$-dimensional vector.

> What is the adjoint operator?

I would like to be able to compute/describe (using math or computer science functions) the adjoint of this map. How can I do that? I know it will have to be $G:\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}\to\mathbb{R}^{pm\times 1}$ but I am unsure about how to find it.

#### Possible Solution

I have been told that the solution looks something like this for $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$
$$
G(y) = \text{vec}(A^\top (y \ominus B)) \in\mathbb{R}^{pm\times 1}
$$

where $y\ominus B$ is the product of each element of $y$ with the corresponding row of $B$, and it is a $n\times p$ matrix.
$$
y \ominus B = \begin{pmatrix}
    y_1b_{11} & \cdots & y_1b_{1p} \\
    \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots \\
    y_n b_{n1} & \cdots & y_n b_{np}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

## Following comments

Following the comments the function $F:\mathbb{R}^{pm\times 1}\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ can be decomposed into the following operations:

- Reshape Operation: $F_1:\mathbb{R}^{pm\times 1}\to \mathbb{R}^{p\times m}$ with $F_1(x) = \texttt{reshape(}x, \texttt{(p,m))} = X$
- Matrix Multiplication $F_2:\mathbb{R}^{p\times m} \to \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ with $F_2(X) = BX$
- Elementwise product: $F_3:\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ with $F_3(X)= A\odot X$
- Reduce sum $F_4:\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ with $F_4(X) = X1_{m\times 1}$

The adjoint of $F$ will be
$$
F^* = (F_4 \circ F_3 \circ F_2 \circ F_1) = F_1^* \circ F_2^* \circ F_3^* \circ F_4^*
$$
Now the adjoint of the reshape operation is the vectorization operation. The adjoint of $F_2(X) = BX$ is simply $F_2^*(X) = B^\top X$. Luckily $A \odot X$ is [self-adjoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303364/adjoint-of-hadamard-product).

Comment: I have no idea what a c.s. function is but. Isn't it the case that your map is the compostion of $4$ maps: $x\mapsto X$, $X\mapsto BX$, $M\mapsto A\odot M$, $L\mapsto L(1,1,\dots,1)^T$. Why not compute the adjoints of these and then compose them (in reverse order)?

Comment: I think your recent edit adding a proposed answer is pretty much what I have suggested.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Oh interesting! Would you mind adding an answer?

Comment: I am quite stuck not gonna lie. How can I find the adjoin of the map $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ that maps $L$ to $L1_m$?

Comment: I was just going to choose bases, work out the matrix, and take its transpose. I think that when you check a vector $y$ just goes to a matrix with $m$ columns each equal to $y$.